# "excited as much as" or "as excited as"

Tags: sentence-construction, comparative-constructions, as

Which one is correct?

> No one made me feel excited **as much as** you did
>
> No one made me feel **as** excited **as** you did

Answer (score 1):

They are both correct, although the first one has two possible meanings.

> No one made me feel excited as much as you did

"As much as" could mean "to the same degree or extent as", or it could refer to frequency (like "as often as" or "as many times as").

> No one made me feel as excited as you did

"As excited as" means "excited to the same degree or extent as".  So it has a clearer meaning.

The second sentence corresponds to one of the two possible meanings of the first sentence.